# PHP parse_ini_file() - where does it look?

Tags: php, file, parsing, path, ini

if I call php's `parse_ini_file("foo.ini")`, in what paths does it look for foo.ini ? 
the include path? the function's documentation doesn't mention it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The filename argument for parse_ini_file is a standard php filename, so the same rules will apply as opening a file using [fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).

You must either specify an absolute file path ("/path/to/my.ini") or a path relative to your current working directory ("my.ini").  See [getcwd](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) for your current working directory.

Unlike the default fopen command, if a relative path is specified ("my.ini") parse_ini_file **will** search include paths after searching your current working directory.  I verified this in php 5.2.6.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine it only looks in the current working directory - See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php if you want to know what that is.

You can always find a path relative to your application by basing it on $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

Answer (score 1):

It could depend on your config but mostly it's current directory and then include_path

Answer (score 0):

By reading the official documentation one can assume that if a relative path is used the file is searched in

- Local folder (where the php file is executed)
- than the include path

But one can provide an absolute path, starting with '/' on *nix or "c:/" on a windows installation.

Read [php.net on `parse_ini_file`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) for more tips